# What is the meaning of "*" in magento custom jQuery

Tags: magento2, jquery

I have a code of jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "magepowSizeGuide":{}
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**What can be the meaning of * ?**

Is this mean that this jQuery will work on all HTML element ?

Comment: I try console.log(this) in this function but it seem like no element select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you understanding through following example:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Pulsestorm_JavascriptInitTutorial/example":{"config":"value"}
        }
    }        
</script>
```

The * we used previously is actually a special case, for programs that don’t need to operate on DOM nodes. The key for this object is actually a CSS/jQuery style selector that tells Magento which DOM nodes the program in `Pulsestorm_JavascriptInitTutorial/example` should operate on.

One of very good reference article: https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you. keep coding :) thanks :) +1 on your question for appreciation

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**"*" Is used to determine that you are using a new module in require js; if you want to add a file to the existing module, you will need to specify the name of the module instead of *.**

Comment: I think it just like element, not module

Comment: used to determine that you are using a new module in require js. existing module need to specify the name of the module

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidDuong My pleasure!